# Constant requests concerning Google and password management

Tags: password

Using Ubuntu 20.04 when I go to a new site in my browser, (Firefox updated only through Ubuntu), I constantly get these dialogue boxes from Google "offering" me a way to use Google for password management.

I have already tried multiple times inside of Google to set the software such that it is not supposed to do this.

How can I get rid of this for good (and everything else Google connected if possible) without messing up my installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: by not using google.com? google is not built into Ubuntu, just switch your default search engine to something else and move on

Comment: this question is unrelated to ubuntu or any other OS,flagged as off topic.

Comment: the comment/question was intended to pertain to any code that google may have put inside the ubuntu installation. my question may have been badly put, but my purpose, as long as it is only google's code that keeps inserting itself into may daily ops, is/was to get rid of every bit of such code.IOW, I am not using google.com and this question did not pertain, in any way, to doing so as a search engine...but rather only that annoying and unrequested dialog box from google, about its password management...something which no other code attempts to do.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the offer to save passwords setting, inside the browser settings.

- Open the browser settings
- Search for password
- Disable offer to save passwords

additionally try to use a different password manager, to be save and have 20 digits random passwords for every service you use and only remember the one important password. This way you stay secure enough for the internet of today. Also enable 2 Factor Authentication where possible.

Comment: thanks so much. will do.is there any other way besides totally disabling asking for passwords?

Comment: unfortunately, in this instance, anyway, disabling the offer did not worl, even after rebooting both ubuntu and firefox. nevertheless, thank you kindly for the suggestions.